# How can I detect if a Chromebook is in developer mode using Javascript in my Chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-os

I'm writing a ChromeOS javascript application that I don't want to be able to run if the Chromebook is in developer mode.  Is there a way for me to determine using JS if the Chromebook is in developer mode?   I couldn't find anything after an exhaustive search.

I did not find any chrome api that shares this information, not yet at least. I found however that there are some terminal commands that only run in developer mode,  but I can not execute terminal commands from web JS.

Comment: Why does your app care?

Comment: One trick I see on some sites is that they have a setInterval to flush console at a relatively high frequency. But that may or may not help you with what you want to achieve. Another method is to whack in lots of [debug] which will pause the app when in developer mode.

Comment: why don't you want to run it if developer mode is on? And wouldn't that stop you from debugging it?

Comment: My application is a test-taking application.  I want to ensure that the device is as secure as possible.

Comment: If it's for security purposes then trying to query the state won't help you; an attacker could just install a custom image that lies about it.

Comment: Look into https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/enterprise_platformKeys and https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=DeviceBlockDevmode